# compiling and running c/c++ programs in-memory

Tags: memory, compilation

Can we compile and run a C/C++ program completely in the memory without need of disk access?

Normally one writes a C/C++ program in editor, saves to disk(in file) and then compiles it. Compiling creates executable file on disk, which one runs to see if it works correctly. What I want to do is to write a program, save to file, invoke gcc/g++ in such a way that it creates machine code but directly loads that on memory to run. So once I am satisfied with program output, I can again invoke gcc/g++(as done usually) to create executable file on disk.

Comment: Yes, systems with no disks do it all the time

Comment: I would like to know then how to do that on the systems with disk.

Comment: Use a RAM disk. FWIW, the question has nothing to do with programming, or C/C++, and belongs on a different site. Of course, you might also be pleasantly surprised to learn that modern systems having something known as a disk cache. And C/C++ compilation tends to be CPU bound anyway.

Comment: Considering that most of the compilation time is spent reading lots of header files from the disk, and analyzing and optimizing the code, I fail to see how the proposed savings would be in any way significant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gcc -pipe` to avoid some temporary files.  And you can pipe the source code into GCC by `gcc -xc -`.   You can even have GCC write its output to stdout:

```
echo 'int main() {}' | gcc -xc - -S -o -
```

Once you've done all that, you are left with a couple issues: where to get GCC from (usually it's on disk!), and where to get the #include and library files you need (ditto).  You could install GCC (it comes with a standard library) onto a RAM disk (look at `/dev/shm`), but is that really what you're trying to accomplish?

You aren't going to speed up compilation this way.  The GCC docs say as much regarding `-pipe`.  If you want faster compilation, improve your source code, implement a parallel build system (`make -j`), and/or use a faster linker, like Gold instead of classic BFD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. An easy way is to use tmpfs.